# Linked Server : Syncing two tables on two SQL Servers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, linked-server, data-synchronization, merge

Suppose these database structure :

```
--On main server(server)
TicketRequest (id, date, count, start, end/*,and some other columns*/)
Ticket (id, reqId, blockedDate, usedDate, userId/*,and some other columns*/)
--and some other tables

--On linked server(gate)
--Just this table
Ticket (id, userId, blockedDate, usedDate)
```

A `Ticket` may use on gate, so on the gate just its `usedDate` may change.

At server, a `Ticket` may blocked, deleted; or after importing gate's data, set its `usedDate`.

I want to sync them online.

I wrote *sp_server_export* , *sp_gate_import* for transport data from server and  *sp_gate_export* , *sp_server_import* for transport data from gate, to sync them via a file(a *server_export* file goes to the gate, and *server_import* file come back to the server).

I used `MERGE` and its performance is really good! Now when I'm trying to find a solution for syncing server with gate, after some searches UNFORTUNATELY found Microsoft says : `MERGE` not working on remote table as target!

So, how I can sync with a transaction from server?!

**NOTE :** As our plan, syncing must only execute from server! Gate operator cannot change DB at all!

**IMPORTANT NOTE :** Consider that concurrency is my first concern! I wanna sync while a user may delete a `Ticket`! Or a `Ticket` may block at the same time! Or at the gate a `Ticket` may use!

**UPDATE :**

Our syncing logic is :

1 - delete old tickets(which returned with a file syncing and have `returnDate` and have `modificationDate >` one month later timestamp to ensure delete used tickets from gate)

2 - update gate.ticket where usedDate is null set blockDate = server.blockDate;

3 - insert new rows from server

4 - set transferDate for Tickets transfered to gate ( i mean new/updated tickets in step 2 and 3 )

5 - update server.Ticket.usedDate from gate.Ticket where gate.Ticket.usedDate is not null. ( this will send used tickets from gate back to server )

6 - insert a transferLog ( in transferLog table on server )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `MERGE` to sync the table on the remote server, but you can't because it's on the remote server...

> From [`MERGE` (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql):
>   *target_table* cannot be a remote table.

...you should still be able to use separate `UPDATE` and `INSERT` statements, for the same effect.

Using the same basic criteria as in the `MERGE`, you should be able to:

1. `UPDATE` all rows that already exist; and
2. `INSERT` any rows that don't already exist.

Doing it in that order avoids updating rows you've just inserted. `MERGE` operations do the `INSERT` and `UPDATE` steps separately in reality, so concurrency issues should be no worse than with `MERGE`.

*<sub>[Community wiki answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki)</sub>*

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered Merge Replication?  This would seem to be a great solution to me.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/merge/merge-replication

Comment: As the article above, Merge Replication could solve synchronize problem in a powerful advanced manner! I am newbie in HUGE sql world, and I think I should continue reading about sql abilities! tnx